# Capturing Mouse and Keyboard Events Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am in a situation where I have to detect that the <kbd>control</kbd> key is pressed or not while dragging an object in JavaScript. If the <kbd>control</kbd> key is pressed then I need to perform some other action.
Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Does control need to be pressed during the whole drag event, or just when the drag ends and the mouse button is released?

Comment: It is to be pressed during whole drag event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey).